# ReflectionFunction Not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

To find where a function is defined in a Laravel application 
I'm trying to do this:

Inside `App\Http\Controllers` Namespace:

```
$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
```

But get an error:

> PHP Error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ReflectionFunction' not
>   found in
>   /var/www/html/s/source/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
>   on line 169

I even tried to use the global namespace:

ReflectionFunction Class is not supposed to be located where laravel is trying to find it, 
But please suggest what is that I could be missing?

Comment: Guys I am sorry for raising a false red flag! It's some other issue, that is causing error this time. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running this code inside class that by itself is inside `namespace App\Http\Controllers`. So you should explicitly define that `ReflectionFunction` class belongs to global namespace:

```
$reflFunc = new \ReflectionFunction('function_name');
print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();
```

Notice `\ReflectionFunction` instead of simple `ReflectionFunction`

Comment: can you think of any reason?

Comment: The reason is lack of global namespace definition for sure, even PHP error gives you a hint about it since it tries to find `ReflectionFunction` inside current namespace. Please re-check that you've tried correct call of the global class

Comment: accepting this answer as you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to `use ReflectionFunction;` in the top of your class. Alternatively change to (notice backslash) `$reflFunc = new \ReflectionFunction('function_name');`

Comment: that is not needed in my view.

Comment: Did you try to include it? I am certain this will resolve your issue.

Comment: If this is still not working, check your code to see if you are calling `ReflectionFunction`in any other parts of your code besides HomeController.php on line 169.

Answer (score 1):

ReflectionFunction is in global namespace.

see:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

To use a class constructor in global namespace write

$reflFunc = new \ReflectionFunction('function_name');

Comment: I tried it, but getting same error. can you think of any reason?